# How do I overcome the npm run dev error (webpack compiled)?

Tags: php, laravel, npm

Currently, I'm doing the project using Laravel framework and Vuexy template. I have done executing these steps as in order:

- "composer install"
- change the .ev.example to .ev file
- "php artisan key:generate"
- "npm install"

However, when executing "npm run dev", I facing an error as below:

```
ERROR in ./resources/assets/js/main.js 48:12-60
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components' in 'C:\laragon\www\borang-ipkaat\resources\assets\js'

webpack compiled with 1 error
```

I have checked the main.js file and thought this might be the problem:

```
const files = require.context('./components', true, /\.vue$/i);
```

I have gone through the several solutions and documentation over hours and still not found the solutions. Thus, may I know is there any ways that can solve the error provided? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct path of `./components` ? please verify if the correct directory is used here.

Comment: Did you mean, that "const files" is pointing out to the incorrect path, it is?

Comment: Yes you need to include the correct path

Comment: Thank you sir! Finally solved the problem, I took the long path to solve it.

Comment: how did you fixed it?

Comment: I change it by pointing to specific directory which is, ./views in resources/assets/js

Comment: Please post as an answer so feature readers can take benefit of your post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to include the correct path

- Answered by: sohail amar